# Azure Active Directory concurrent user(same credential) logins

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way we can limit concurrent(same credential) logins in Azure Active Directory?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limiting concurrent logins is not currently supported in Azure Active Directory. One workaround is that you could limit the login hour for the user, or you could enable Multi-Factor Authentication(MFA) to enhance the login security level and reduce the login risk. For example, once you enable MFA, you could require the user who is logging in to confirm by using a phone call or text code after entering the user password. This will have the same effect of restricting multiple users from sharing an account. (It won't prevent this fully, but it will make it more tedious to do.)

You can also make a feature request in User Voice for this feature. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will do that.

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps.